# Why does my CSS mask code not work in Firefox?

Tags: css, firefox, mask

I want to make a mask on an image.

It's working fine in Chrome, so I must be doing something right.

This is the code:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .element {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #fff;
    background: url(images/film.png);
    mask:url(images/cat.svg);
    -webkit-mask-image: url(images/cat.svg);
  }
</style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="element">
  </div><img src="images/cat.svg" width="250" height="250" />
</body>
```

Viewable here: [kindervakantiepas.nl/mask/mask.html](http://kindervakantiepas.nl/mask/mask.html)

Why is it not working in Firefox?

Comment: Your `<div class="element">` does not contain the `<img.../>`. Are you sure this is correct?

Comment: @fearis Please don't modify the code given by the author of the question. Your edit might be a good answer but editing the question itself only results in confusion.

Answer (score 10):

The problem is the svg itself. You didn't define a mask. I had a simular problem in another project and came up with an svg like this. You'll find a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/axelmichel/DrEPj/):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd" [
    <!ENTITY ns_svg "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <!ENTITY ns_xlink "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
]>
<svg xmlns="&ns_svg;" xmlns:xlink="&ns_xlink;" width="313.204" height="377.418" viewBox="0 0 313.204 377.418" >
<defs>
    <mask id="maskid" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox">
    <polygon stroke="#FFFFFF" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="56.609,171.248 116.609,207.586 189.849,165.896 182.243,136.037 
    174.638,108.994 208.159,98.854 209.849,74.628 189.567,59.698 200.553,38.008 181.116,58.572 163.651,56.037 154.074,32.938 
    156.328,54.064 148.722,59.98 148.44,83.642 118.018,92.375 78.863,111.248 69.286,144.769 50.13,86.177 "/>
    </mask>
</defs>
<g>
<polygon stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="56.609,171.248 116.609,207.586 189.849,165.896 182.243,136.037 
    174.638,108.994 208.159,98.854 209.849,74.628 189.567,59.698 200.553,38.008 181.116,58.572 163.651,56.037 154.074,32.938 
    156.328,54.064 148.722,59.98 148.44,83.642 118.018,92.375 78.863,111.248 69.286,144.769 50.13,86.177 "/>
</g>
</svg>
```

For FF you use the mask via the id reference (in this example: maskid):

And in CSS:

```
.element {
    background: url("images/film.png") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 250px;
    mask: url("images/cat.svg#maskid");
    -webkit-mask-image: url(images/cat.svg);
}
```

Comment: yep i only needed to add a mask element in my svg... thanx!

Comment: @WouterBerkes: in that case, if you could accept this answer (by clicking the tick next to it), then people who find this page later can see how to solve the problem too.

Comment: hm, but that will mean that every svg file will be sort of about twice bigger.